# Bootstrap table with list and grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, responsive

I need a bootstrap responsive table to list and grid view options, I have already tried many times did not get it. List and grid view showing only dive options I need table data and list grid view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin for that

Jquery pluging

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/List-View-Grid-View-Switcher-Plugin-jQuery-simple-list-grid/

Bootstrap sample:

https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/zIBjJ

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well well-sm">
        <strong>Display</strong>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" id="list" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">
            </span>List</a> <a href="#" id="grid" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Grid</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="products" class="row list-group">
        <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
                    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                        Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <p class="lead">
                                $21.000</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
                    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                        Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <p class="lead">
                                $21.000</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
                    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                        Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <p class="lead">
                                $21.000</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
                    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                        Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <p class="lead">
                                $21.000</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
                    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                        Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <p class="lead">
                                $21.000</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
                    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                        Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <p class="lead">
                                $21.000</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replay, but i have already tried it did not get it proper result, i need table with list and grid option. My table data below

Comment: do you mean like https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/bm97x6uv/ here its based on responsiveness of layout it will display either table or list view layout

Comment: yes same like this but i want list and grid option view

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Country</th>
                      <th>Languages</th>
                      <th>Population</th>
                      <th>Median Age</th>
                      <th>Area (Km²)</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Argentina</td>
                      <td>Spanish (official), English, Italian, German, French</td>
                      <td>41,803,125</td>
                      <td>31.3</td>
                      <td>2,780,387</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Australia</td>
                      <td>English 79%, native and other languages</td>
                      <td>23,630,169</td>
                      <td>37.3</td>
                      <td>7,739,983</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Greece</td>
                      <td>Greek 99% (official), English, French</td>
                      <td>11,128,404</td>
                      <td>43.2</td>
                      <td>131,956</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Luxembourg</td>
                      <td>Luxermbourgish (national) French, German (both administrative)</td>
                      <td>536,761</td>
                      <td>39.1</td>
                      <td>2,586</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Russia</td>
                      <td>Russian, others</td>
                      <td>142,467,651</td>
                      <td>38.4</td>
                      <td>17,076,310</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Sweden</td>
                      <td>Swedish, small Sami- and Finnish-speaking minorities</td>
                      <td>9,631,261</td>
                      <td>41.1</td>
                      <td>449,954</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```